# Is there a way to simplify a multivalued function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

A minimal example is

```
FullSimplify[Exp[-I*x] Sqrt[Exp[I*2 x]], Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
```

which will just return the same input. However, what I expect to see is \pm 1 (here \pm means plus or minus)because Sqrt[Exp[I*2 x]] can be factored out to be Exp[I*(x+n* Pi)] and further equals (\pm 1) Exp[I*x].

If that is not possible, can I write some my own simplification rules to simplify this multivalued function, which only takes one of the roots, for example Exp[I*x]?

Comment: `Exp[-I*x] Sqrt[Exp[I*2 x]] // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> x > 0] & ` gives `E^(I Pi Floor[1/2 - x/Pi]) `  and  `E^(I Pi Floor[1/2 - x/Pi]) // FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {x > 0}] & ` gives `(-1)^Floor[1/2 - x/Pi] `

Comment: Thank you! Would you please write it as an answer so that I can pick you as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With square roots, PowerExpand with conditions often helps.

```
Exp[-I*x] Sqrt[Exp[I*2 x]] // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> x > 0] & 

(*   E^(I Pi Floor[1/2 - x/Pi])    *)

E^(I Pi Floor[1/2 - x/Pi]) // FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {x > 0}] & 

(*   (-1)^Floor[1/2 - x/Pi]   *)
```